# App Engine charts show zero activity although no errors reported?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am testing out a new app and noticed whilst looking at my reports that for a period of approximately 1 hour all charts showed zero activity. I.e. Requests/Second, CPU Seconds Used, Instances all display zero, when they shouldn't be as the app receives a constant supply of traffic. Note: Error/Second shows no errors for that time period.

This screenshot conveys this:

[image: http://imgur.com/QYXDW]

I have looked in my logs and during that period it shows I still received traffic and requests were handled successfully - which is puzzling.

Has anyone else noticed such an anomaly or is this likely to be an issue with my app!

Thanks

Comment: Please embed images in your questions, rather than linking to them externally - external links have a tendency to go away.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a reporting issue - your site was getting traffic, and serving it fine, but the infrastructure that collects stats failed to do so for a short while. Check your logs to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me today ~(6/11/2011) also, I think its a one time flock.
Its probably a result of the switching to the new billing model.